# Get objects that are referenced by another model in Django

Tags: django

I have an employee model and a Position model. Also, I have many positions that are available in the system (more than 2000).

I need to show the positions that are only used in the system. and ignore the others using a `QuerySet` in Django.

in SQL I would do something like this.

```
    SELECT
        * 
    FROM 
        positions 
    WHERE 
        position_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT position_id from employees)
```

In Django I couldn't find a way to do it. **The problem with creating a list of the employees positions**

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name=_('first_name'))
    position = models.ForeignKey('core.Position', verbose_name=_('Position'))


class Position(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    #....


# query is to get the positions that are used by employees. Not one employee. ALL employees.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with going the reverse direction on the ForeignKeyField relationship.

```
Position.objects.filter(employee_set__isnull=False)
```